# Oauth2 password grant type with Doorkeeper and Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I've got a Rails API that is using Doorkeeper with the password grant method for Oauth2.

Doorkeeper requires both the `client_id` and `client_secret` to be sent to the token request (`/oauth/token`), alongside the user's login details and scope.

How would I go about doing this in an Angular app? I don't like the idea of storing the client id and secret client side...

Comment: Take a look of our flow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455132/is-this-concept-of-oauth2-workflow-for-sinatra-angular-js-custom-provider-co we are Also not sure about that and ask for opinion

Comment: @BartekS did you get anywhere with your implementation?

Comment: try this https://github.com/bslipek/angurailsSpike/tree/satelizer but not well documented :)

Comment: @BartekS Thanks, but that doesn't seem to use the API / Oauth the authenticate the user, but rather uses a regular rails controller to login and manually return a token...

Comment: Correct, you need to login user after each request on you backend. you decode JWT token and search for spec user (veryfied secret first). But yes, it is compicated :) try segments branch also...

Answer (score 2):

The client_id and client_secret should only be used when your app code is secured, i.g. inside your web server.

For browser web apps and mobile apps the oauth implicit flow or the password flow should be used.

1. In the implicit flow, you only use the client_id.
2. In the password flow, you exchange the username and password for an access token.

Comment: Is valid OAuth spec for the server to provide any `scope` you request when creating tokens with password flow? I've seeing libs doing that and I am curious if that is the expected flow and then the some api endpoint should beside authorize the request based on token scope to also check if that user/entity has privileges to do it so.